# how to change color of just the Content in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

I wish to change just the color of heading 'Contents' in table of contents. I am using the simple `\tableof contents` command in my document

[image]

This is the main page code

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{images/}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.9in}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\include{chapters/Cover/Coverpage}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapters/0-Abstract/Abstract}
\include{chapters/1-Introduction/general}
\include{chapters/2-GamificationDesignPrinciples/general}
\include{chapters/3-MOOC+SRL/MOOC+SRL}
\include{chapters/4-ProjectDesc/project_desc}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography/references}

\end{document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you provide `MWE" of your code?

Comment: Updated the question with the main page code

Answer (score 1):

To change just the title of the table of contents (and not for other sections), put the following in your preamble:

```latex
\let\oldcontentsname\contentsname 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\color{red}\oldcontentsname}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know that contents are like section name. I wanted to change the color of all subsections and sections of my document and  I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275770/modifying-section-to-make-it-colorful-with-latex

To my pleasant surprise it changed the color of the Contents as well.

Code is pretty simple as follows:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\color{Blue}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{Blue}\thesection}{1em}{}
```